# Transform text into gibberish while maintains the "look" of the original text

Tags: open-source, library, text-processing, utility

I have some text. I want to generate gibberish instead of this text, but I want the gibberish to look the same, in the sense of being sequence of words of more-or-less the same lengths as the original sequence; and the same punctuation marks, line breaks and such. You can also think of this as a transformation of the original text, replacing existing words with gibberish-words of similar length.

Is there some FOSS tool which does this, and runs on Linux? Otherwise, perhaps a library I could use to do this easily?

Notes:

- If it helps, you may assume the text is in English, constitutes a single paragraph, and has no "weird" characters anywhere.
- I don't just want to generate a sequence of gibberish words; the correspondence to the original text's word lengths is important.
- I'd also like to maintain the original text's punctuation marks, but let's not make that a constraint.

Comment: look up markov chains

Comment: You might want to search for a "lorem generator".

Comment: OP's comment to my answer is that his objective is to transform existing text. Obviously, this parameter belongs in an edit to the original post, to eliminate incorrect suggestions/answers.

Comment: @fred_dot_u: Edited.

Comment: can you provide example input/output to provide a sense of what you're looking for

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with linux to answer this aspect, but isn't there a text facility built into linux that one can use to create a script to solve this task? Perhaps a migration to the linux SE will provide a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

A [markov chain](https://setosa.io/ev/markov-chains/) tells you the probability of hopping, or "transitioning," from one state to any other state (or from one word to another), thus being able to generate fake text that looks real. [Online demo](https://www.dcode.fr/markov-chain-text)

[Python](https://github.com/jsvine/markovify) library

[Go](https://github.com/mb-14/gomarkov) library

[ruby](https://github.com/zolrath/marky_markov) library

Comment: I don't need it to look real; I just need it to have similar lengths to my original text.

Comment: @einpoklum `I want the gibberish to look the same, in the sense of being sequence of words of more-or-less, the same lengths as the original sequence`, makes it sound like you want it to look real (and markov chains will generate gibberish often). Why not just use lorem ipsum if you don't care if its gibberish?

Answer (score 0):

Using search terms "text filler generator" and "english language text filler generator" provided a number of free, web based resources. One of them is a compilation of the ["best" eleven available](https://wpamelia.com/dummy-text-generator/), but that's subjective, of course.

One of the [results presented](http://www.fillerama.io/) an option to theme the created text, based on a variety of current sociological resources, such as Star Wars, Futurama, Monty Python and others. It seemed to be a bit more frivolous than your objective, but is included in the link to be thorough.

[Yet another resource](https://smodin.io/writer) requires a user-created title and generates a document based on the AI algorithm's interpretation of the title. It appears to be better suited and well formatted. This latter one seems to provide one free use, perhaps three and may require creating an account for more frequent use.

Comment: Those do not do what I've asked for. They generate basically-unconstrained text; I'm talking about transforming existing text.